# Simple responsive html height issue

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

i'm creating a simple responsive html template with only 3 rows, header, body, footer and images for footer and header, as well as background image for body. Now my footer isn't fixed on the bottom, i would like my max height to be 1024px.

Here's an image how it's supposed to look: [image]

And here's what i've got: [image]

I have no idea what is wrong with my code... I've tried many combinations of css.

Here's my full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Put your title here</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
    html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 1024px; 
      background-image: url(landing-page3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.wrapper {
height: 100%;
}
.main {
height: 70%;
}
.header {
height: 15%;
}
.footer {
height: 15%;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<img src="headerf.png" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div id="main">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div id="footer">
<img src="footer.png" style="width:100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem** you have set `footer` as `#` (id) in html but in css, you have defined it as a `.`(class)

you **css** says :

```
.footer {
   height: 15%;
}
```

your **html** says

```
<div id="footer">
```

Solution :

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative /* added */
 }
 #footer {
    position:absolute; /* added */
    height: 15%;
    bottom:0; /* added - fix to bottom */
    left:0; /* added -for full width */
    right:0; /* added -for full width */
}
```

**Also**,in you `html,body` you have set `max-height` but not `height`, so height of parent elemt of wrapper is not defined, so it doesn't inherit `100%` of browser height

```
 html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 1024px;
        height: 100%;/*missing*/
        background-image: url(landing-page3.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7E338/1/)

---

**EDIT**

Rather then placing `img` in `footer`....set it as `background`

```
     #footer {
         min-height: 15%; /* will wrap content if it higher than 15% :) */
         width:100%;
         background-image: url(http://www.smarthosting.rs/footer.png);
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-size: 100% 100%;
     }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r7G4z/4/)

Comment: The point is, i need it to be 100% height, from next element (for example) 15% footer, 15% header, 70% body (min-height), so my elements will always has the same proportion...

Comment: @JognSmit : updated the answer and fiddle...check if it helps!

Comment: NoobEditor, your jsfiddle is messed up i guess? Footer is on left side  ?

Comment: @JognSmit What he's saying is max-height sets a limit for body and html height, but it doesn't define to the browser what that height is. In order for percentages of child elements to work their parents must have defined heights. html and body need a defined height of 100% in order for the following elements to know what their 15% 15% and 70% are of.

Comment: @JognSmit : mate, i expect you to have some knowledge of basic css before telling me that my fiddle is messed up....see the green border in this fiddle, that's `footer` => http://jsfiddle.net/7E338/2/ i have not aligned text in center or linked your images!! :D

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see that he had "footer" inside of footer div, that's why i thought it's messed up.

Comment: @JognSmit : no probs...see the fiddle i posted in comment...its same as one in my answer, except for the green border :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I've used your example on my work and i still hasn't solve my problem, here's what i've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/r7G4z/ (I've linked my images so expect it to load a little bit slower as images are huge (i still haven't optimize them)). However, text isn't showing properly...

Comment: @NoobEditor It should expand the main div, so footer is always on the bottom, but look at original image of my OP, blue text should be inside of a main div. I guess it should be scrollable ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46663/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-jogn-smit)

Comment: @NoobEditor Header and footer images should be above background image, while text should be between header and footer, and above background image if that was your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a sticky footer. It is explained clearly in [Chris Coyer - Sticky Footer example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/). Use and adapt to the way you want it. Hopefully, this article will help you.

Comment: Wouldn't that mess up point of responsive? If i fix a height of footer?